# Ubuntu Server 23.10 + Kodi GBM: Poor bluetooth audio quality

Tags: sound, bluetooth, kodi

I've built Kodi GBM (for HDR not supported by Linux window managers) on Ubuntu Server 23.10 and I'm having a problem with audio over bluetooth. Following the instructions found on the internet, I installed Pipewire and bluetooth support. The sound quality is apparently good, but I can hear crackling etc. Sound over cable is good.

Please advise how to install full and working audio and bluetooth support on Ubuntu Server 23.10?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem after Nvidia driver update. In logs was found that updates touched the next modules:

> bluez bluez-cups libbluetooth3

I did a lot of googling but nothing helped until I found this post:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/

However, I'm not sure if you have to do all the steps in the post. A colleague of mine fixed the problem just with one command:

```
sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
```

If this won't help, do all the steps from the link.